# Node JS hosting using Nginx Reverse proxy gives 404 error

Tags: node.js, wordpress, nginx, digital-ocean, nginx-reverse-proxy

I want to host a Nodejs API server to my digitalocean server where a WordPress application is already running using Nginx and PHP fpm

I followed the below link to set up the WordPress application and it's working fine now.
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-configure-nginx-as-a-web-server-and-reverse-proxy-for-apache-on-one-ubuntu-18-04-server

I wanted to set up Nodejs application inside the same server for demo purposes and I followed the digitalocean guide for setting up node js with a different config file and subdomain.

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-a-node-js-application-for-production-on-ubuntu-16-04

My Nginx config for node application looks like this

```
server {
server_name sub.domain.com
location / {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:6969;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
}
```

}

I have allowed port 6969 using ***ufw allow 6969***.

I am able to access the Nodejs application using ***sub.domain.com:6969*** but ***sub.domain.com*** gives me a 404 error. (404 Not Found nginx/1.18.0 (Ubuntu))

I want to access Nodejs application directly without a port number. I have checked  Nginx logs and there are no errors, and configures is gives success in ***nginx -t***

Please give me some suggestions to debug and fix this issue. I don't have much knowledge in Nginx configuration. I was just following tutorials from Digitalocean to configure the WordPress and node application.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Why are you using the old ubuntu 16 guide? https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-a-node-js-application-for-production-on-ubuntu-20-04

Comment: Please post your full nginx config. Have you reloaded the nginx server after changes in the configuration? Post your error & access log

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing the port

```
server {
server_name sub.domain.com;
listen: 80;

location / {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:6969;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
}
```

Comment: I have tried that before. As you comment again tried with port too.  Still giving me the sane 404 error.

Comment: did you put the conf in /sites-enabled/ and reload nginx?

Comment: you can access by port number because your app is listening on that port, and you did not have any firewall. It has nothing to do with nginx. You may want to turn on access log and error log and see what is the error message.

Comment: Thanks, mate. It worked. I forgot to link the config file to site-enabled.

Comment: remember to turn on ufw so your app can only be accessed by nginx - https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-a-firewall-with-ufw-on-ubuntu-18-04